# extracting specific cell content from every csv row to file in awk

Tags: xml, csv, awk

I have a csv file mixing csv and xml in a way that some csv columns contains xml.

I need to extract every xml to file for further processing.

```
v1,v2,             v3,      v4,  v5
a,<xml>.....</xml>,alberta, 2012, 2021
b,<xml>.....</xml>,manitoba, 2021,2022
......
```

my first approach is using awk, but not very versed on it and this is extracting all the column. I want every cell into a new file.

```
awk '{print $2}' file.csv > outfile
```

Comment: If your XML field or any field before it can contain commas then include that in the example in your question.

Comment: no commas. thanks for pointing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what data is in that XML chunk this may be very brittle, but if your particular case allows it, you could use this command (requires GNU `awk`, see Ed Morton's comment for additional observations):

```
awk -F, 'NR > 1 { print $2 > "xml-" (NR-1) ".xml" }' temp.csv
```

- `-F,` set the field separator to be a comma
- `NR > 1` will skip the header, by applying the logic in between braces `{}` just to records whose index is greater than 1 (each row in the file is a record)
- `print $2 >` will print the 2nd field in the record to a file
- `"xml-" (NR-1) ".xml"` this builds up the filename using string concatenation denoted using juxtaposition. `NR` is again the record number.

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU awk for a) unparenthesized right side of output redirection not causing a syntax error (what you have now is undefined behavior), and b) leaving all output files open not causing a "too many open files error" once you get past some threshold which could be as low as a bout 15 files. To work in any awk you'd need `'NR > 1 { out = "xml-" (NR-1) ".xml"; print > out; close(out) }'`

Comment: @EdMorton thank you. I'm still new to `awk`, so your remarks are helpful. In particular, I didn't know the file should be closed. As for the first point, I've run my snippet using the `awk` that ships with macOS, so maybe I was just lucky in its handling of this undefined behaviour.

Comment: You're welcome. The awk that ships with macOS is BSD awk so I'm extremely surprised that that didn't give you a syntax error. Are you sure you aren't picking up GNU awk (try `awk --version`).

Comment: @EdMorton ah, you are right. It was indeed GNU awk, which I must have installed some time in the past but totally forgot about it. I was thinking that only the `gawk` executable is GNU awk, but it symlinked to `awk` too. Well, thanks again, now I know my system better.